# div relative position and sizing

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to set out a page layout within a containing `div`. I've been back and forth over what combination of `height`, `min-height`, `width`, `min-width`, and `position` I need to do this - and additionally what the role of `width`, `height`, `viewBox`, and `preserveAspectRatio` would be on the `svg`. I've been fiddling for hours. Here is a minimal example:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="left-img"></div>
  <div id="right-box">
    <div id="header-text">
    text text text text text
    </div>
    <div id="svg-container">
      <svg style="background_color:red;"></svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The requirements are that

- `left-img` is at least 250px widte and no more than 35% of the width of `container`
- `left-img` and `right-box` together take the entire width of `container` and each be full height
- `container` should have height `100vh` unless `header-text` needs more height for its contents
- `header-text` plus its margin should not overflow `container` onto
  the next div in the layout
- `header-text` should be set in by `2em` from the boundary of `right-box`
- the svg should be the full height and width of `right-box` and behind `header-text` (plus the margin on `header-text`)
- when the window is resized, the svg should continue to fill the space behind `header-text`
- the svg should never have more height than the picture, even when the window is resized

The last requirement about svg size is key and the cause of much of my woe. Any ideas about what I should do achieve these requirements?

Edit - some drawings

[image: normal layout]

[image: narrow layout - after window resize]

Comment: please add a drawing. A drawing of an intended layout is easier to understand then a text

Comment: Who/what is setting the width of container? I see it has to be at least (250px*100/35) wide but other than that can it be anything? Oh, and what has window size got to do with it?

Comment: Yes - container can be any width (it's as wide as the window, right now, so when the window is resized it is also resized). left-img is max(250px, 35%) at the moment

Comment: max(250px, 35%) does not satisfy the mandated minimum width for the left hand side of 250px on narrow viewports. That requirement plus the max 35% requirement means that the container has a minimum width (which on narrow viewports will be greater than 100vw). Hence my question, I don't think container can be just 'any width'.

Comment: Oh yes, on narrow viewports I just get rid of the image totally! Sorry for not being clear about that

Comment: Could you add that to your question as one of the conditions as it's rather vital!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what kind of layout you are doing! I hope I have met all the requirements.

For the SVG part, the only way I have found to respect the height of the image, is to use javascript, and you must at least know the height and width of the image (or if you use the TAG `img`, instead of `background-image`, you can get the dimensions automatically from javascript).

Check it in full screen, because otherwise it's not very easy to understand.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function calcSVG() {
    let imgHeight = 400;
    let imgWidth = 300;
    let ratio = imgWidth / imgHeight;
    let svgHeight = $('#left-img').width() / ratio;

    $('#svg-container svg').css('height', svgHeight + 'px');
  }

  $(window).resize(function() {
    calcSVG();
  });

  calcSVG();

  let counter = 0;
  let clearI = setInterval(function() {
    $('#header-text span').append(' text text text text texttext text text text texttext text text text texttext text text text texttext text text text texttext text text text texttext text text text texttext text text text texttext text text text texttext text text text texttext text text text texttext text text text texttext text text text texttext text text text texttext text text text texttext text text text texttext text text text texttext text text text texttext text text text texttext text text text texttext text text text texttext text text text texttext text text text text');
    counter++;
    if (counter > 5) clearInterval(clearI);
  }, 2000);

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(250px, 30%) 1fr;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}

#left-img {
  background-color: violet;
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/300/400');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

#right-box {
  position: relative;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 2em;
}

#header-text {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #ffffff75;
}

#header-text span {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 15px;
}

#svg-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#svg-container svg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="left-img"></div>
  <div id="right-box">
    <div id="header-text">
      <span>text text text text text</span>
    </div>
    <div id="svg-container">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 48 48" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                <path d="M23.1,38.8L32.5,21h-7.2V9.2L15.5,27h7.6V38.8z M24,48c-3.3,0-6.4-0.6-9.3-1.9s-5.5-3-7.6-5.2c-2.2-2.2-3.9-4.7-5.2-7.7
                    S0,27.3,0,24c0-3.3,0.6-6.4,1.9-9.4s3-5.5,5.2-7.6s4.7-3.9,7.6-5.1S20.7,0,24,0c3.3,0,6.4,0.6,9.4,1.9s5.5,3,7.6,5.1
                    c2.2,2.2,3.9,4.7,5.1,7.6s1.9,6,1.9,9.4c0,3.3-0.6,6.4-1.9,9.3s-3,5.5-5.1,7.7c-2.2,2.2-4.7,3.9-7.6,5.2S27.3,48,24,48z"/>
            </svg>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is wonderful! the JS keeps adding text to header-text but I think that isn't relevant to the layout question. I'll dig in and figure out how you've got it to work! Thank you :)

Comment: @MarkC. The javascript interval was useful for proving your third condition: `container should have height 100vh unless header-text needs more height for its contents`.